# Como simplificar esses dois métodos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, classes

Bom, na minha classe existe dois métodos mágicos, add e sub:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    if other.__m == self.__m and other.__n == self.__n:
        result = []

        for i in range(other.__m):
            lst = []

            for j in range(other.__n):
                lst.append(self.elems[i][j] + other.elems[i][j])

            result.append(lst)

        return Matrix(result)

def __sub__(self, other):
    if other.__m == self.__m and other.__n == self.__n:
        result = []

        for i in range(other.__m):
            lst = []

            for j in range(other.__n):
                lst.append(self.elems[i][j] - other.elems[i][j])     

            result.append(lst)
        return Matrix(result)
```

Como podem perceber, a única diferença entre elas é que num determinado momento uma soma e outra subtrai. Sabendo dessa única diferença, eu queria uma maneira de simplificar elas afim de diminuir o código.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode criar uma função que aceite a operação (soma, subtração ou outro) como argumento, e depois chamar essa função modificando só a operação desejada.

Como não temos a função direta, só o operador, e a função varia dependendo do tipo da classe dos operandos, importamos `operator` pra nos disponibilizar a função referente à operação correta:

```
import operator

def _fn_base(self, other, op):
    if other.__m == self.__m and other.__n == self.__n:
        result = []

        for i in range(other.__m):
            lst = []

            for j in range(other.__n):
                lst.append(op(self.elems[i][j], other.elems[i][j]))

            result.append(lst)

        return Matrix(result)

def __add__(self, other):
    return self._fn_base(other, operator.add)

def __sub__(self, other):
    return self._fn_base(other, operator.sub)
```

Answer (score 3):

Além de você criar um método auxiliar que recebe o operador como parâmetro, como mostrado nas outras respostas, você pode fazer uso de outros métodos mágicos para simplificar a lógica da sua classe.

Considere a classe inicial:

```
class Matrix:

    def __init__(self, matrix):
        self.matrix = matrix
```

Você pode fazer com que seu objeto seja iterável ao definir o método `__iter__`:

```
class Matrix:

    def __init__(self, matrix):
        self.matrix = matrix


    def __iter__(self):
        yield from iter(self.matrix)
```

Desta forma, você pode iterar sobre as linhas da matriz com o `for`:

```
>>> m = Matrix([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])

>>> for linha in m:
...     print(linha)

[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
```

Você pode utilizar o método `__len__` para retornar a dimensão da matriz:

```
class Matrix:

    def __init__(self, matrix):
        self.matrix = matrix


    def __iter__(self):
        yield from iter(self.matrix)


    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.matrix)
```

E, assim, fazer:

```
>>> print(len(m))
2
```

Você pode implementar o método `__getitem__` para facilitar o acesso às linhas da matriz:

```
class Matrix:

    def __init__(self, matrix):
        self.matrix = matrix


    def __iter__(self):
        yield from iter(self.matrix)


    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.matrix)


    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.matrix[key]
```

Podendo fazer:

```
>>> print(m[0])
[1, 2, 3]
```

Finalmente, implementando os métodos de adição e subtração, a sua classe poderia ficar como:

```
class Matrix:

  def __init__(self, matrix):
    self.matrix = matrix


  @property
  def size(self):
    return (len(self), len(self[0]))


  def __iter__(self):
    yield from iter(self.matrix)


  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.matrix)


  def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self.matrix[key]


  def __add__(self, other):
    if self.size != other.size:
      raise Exception('Matrizes de tamanhos diferentes')

    return Matrix(
      [
        [self[i][j] + other[i][j] for j in range(len(self[i]))] 
          for i in range(len(self))
      ]
    )


  def __sub__(self, other):
    if self.size != other.size:
      raise Exception('Matrizes de tamanhos diferentes')

    return Matrix(
      [
        [self[i][j] - other[i][j] for j in range(len(self[i]))] 
          for i in range(len(self))
      ]
    )
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas eu já estava fazendo essas coisas que tu me recomendou kk, mesmo assim obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Olá, amigo!
Você pode incluir um novo parâmetro no método e realizar a operação conforme o valor do mesmo. Exemplo:

```
def __action__(self, other, mat_operation):
    if other.__m == self.__m and other.__n == self.__n:
        result = []

        for i in range(other.__m):
            lst = []

            for j in range(other.__n):
                if (mat_operation == 1):
                    lst.append(self.elems[i][j] + other.elems[i][j])
                elif(mat_operation == 2):
                    lst.append(self.elems[i][j] - other.elems[i][j])
                else:
                    #another operation


            result.append(lst)

        return Matrix(result)



__action__(other, 1)
```

Espero ter ajudado.
Abraços,

Comment: Olá, eu já estava pensando em fazer algo parecido com o que você fez, mas estava com receio de que ficasse ineficiente, visto que a cada elemento teria que verificar qual a operação, mesmo assim muito obrigado pela resposta!